# How to use MS Sql Stored Procedure in Asp.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im using VS2012, MVC4 C#, SQL 2008 R2

I have a stored procedure which returns a list contains two computed columns. In my SP I have two parameters which I need to pass from View, these parameters will be generated from javascript on page load and stored in HiddenFields.

I have followed this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864271/calling-a-stored-procedure-mvc4), when I created a reference like

```
Rest Context = new Rest();
List<Rest> RT = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery......
```

I get an error.

Could someone tell me the right way to call a stored procedure and pass values from View.

Comment: You might consider posting the error.

Comment: @alan Model doest contain ExecuteStoreQuery and no extension method

Comment: Given the error above I'm assuming the code you outlined in your question is in the view.
You want to create a model to use in your view, this model can be populated in the controller by calling the sproc.
How familiar are you with MVC4?

Comment: Ive figured out this question, below is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got o/p with Model, View and Controller

In my Model class, I have two .cs files, DefaultConnection.cs and Rest.cs

```
public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Rest> Restart { get; set; }
}
```

In Rest.cs

```
public class Rest
{
    //These two properties are columns in Stored Procedure, Id -PK, 
    //Distance - Computed column in SP
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public double Distance { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller

```
Public ActionResult Get_Data()
{
    DefaultConnection Context = new DefaultConnection();
    IEnumerable<Rest> results = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Rest>
        ("Your SP @para1 = xyz, @para2 = abc") //If you have parameters or ("Just SP")
        .ToList();
    return View(results);
}
```

In View

```
@using MVC.Models
@model IEnumerable<Rest>

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "GetData";
 }

 <h2>GetData</h2>

 @foreach (Rest rt in @Model)
 {
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>@rt.Id</td><td></td>
           <td>@rt.Distance</td>
        </tr>
   </table>

 }
```