# mvc 4 Stored Proc - how to set up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. There already is an existing database.

How do I use the existing database? I updated the `web.config`. But what else do I need to do?
Also how do I call a stored procedure from with in ASP.NET MVC?

More info..

The current database was created to be used with classic asp. So it was not created using EF at all.

All I need to do at the moment is wanting to call a stored procedure from the SQL Server database and get the results from that stored procedure.

The call to the stored procedure from SQL is

```
exec xscs_sw_PO_quote_form_PDF_pr 885,1,1
```

Thanks

Comment: MVC doesn't know anything about sql, and has no code related to doing anything database oriented.  You can call your stored procs just like you would in any .net application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are alot of different variables when working with an existing database. Is this database built dynamically using EF from a previous project? If it is then that makes things easier. You'd have to make sure your models matched up with database structure. You would need to use database migrations if you were expanding existing tables with your models as well.

This is just a few things that what would need to be done assuming the above scenario.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these stored procedure?

Comment: So why can't you just run SQL queries in your controllers?

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do this? when you mean run sql queries you mean run the stored proc yeah?

Comment: Are these stored procedures stored in tables within the database or do you want to define procedures on this database from within your new MVC application?

Comment: I don't want to define the procedures.  The procedures are already defined on the sql database.  All I want to do is call the stored proc from mvc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371131/how-to-use-ms-sql-stored-procedure-in-asp-net-mvc4 See this question, I think it answers your question.